# Looping over duplicates as one.

Tags: r, interpolation

I have two datasets dataA and dataB with columns: id, posX and value. The two datasets have different sampling rates i.e. the number of rows are not equal for the same id. I am doing a sort of interpolation:

```
interp <- function(coil, coilY){
  n <- nrow(coil)
  Y <- matrix(0,nrow = n,ncol = 1)

  for (i in 1:n){
    ind <- order(abs(coil[i,1]-coilY[,1]),decreasing = FALSE)[1:2]#coil[i,1] = inpos and coilY[,1]=outpos
    if(coilY[ind[1],1]==coilY[ind[2],1]){
      Y[i] <- (coilY[ind[1],2]-coilY[ind[2],2])/2
    } else {
      Y[i] <- ((coilY[ind[1],2]-coilY[ind[2],2])/(coilY[ind[1],1]-coilY[ind[2],1]))*(coil[i,1]-coilY[ind[1],1]) + coilY[ind[1],2]
    }
  }
  return(Y)
}
```

The issue is in the above code I assume that at each iteration same id for datA and datB is considered i.e.

```
>dataA
id  posX val
1    2    .4
1    3    .4
1    4    .7

>dataB
id  posX val
1    1    .4
1    2    .4
1    3    .7
1    4    .8
1    5    .9
```

In the above scenario, I can ignore the id and do interpolation. However, when I have many duplicate id's how can I adjust the `interp` function or how can I loop through by considering rows of id 1,2,...,100 at each iteration. The problem is for the following type of data.

```
   >dataA
    id  posX val
    1    2    .4
    1    3    .4
    2    4    .7
    ..
    >dataB
    id  posX val
    1    1    .4
    1    2    .4
    2    3    .7
    2    4    .8
    2    5    .9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept working on the problem and the following solution worked for me:

**Creating lists**

```
coil<-split(dataA$posX, dataA$id)
coilY<-split(dataB$val, dataB$id)
coilY1<-split(dataB$posX, dataB$id)
lst<-list()
```

**Looping**

Looping over the list and converting each element of list as matrix, becuse function `interpt` can only deal with matrices.

```
for (i in 1:length(coil)){
lst[[i]]<-interp(as.matrix(coil[[i]]),cbind(as.matrix(coilY1[[i]]),as.matrix(coilY[[i]])))
}
```

**Conversion**

The obtained answer is in the list format, to convert it to a matrix:

```
ans<-as.matrix(unlist(lst))
```